# R - Group by correlation, remove duplicate and put the frame back?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, grouping, correlation

The VarA and VarB colomn are the output of variables which are perfectly colinear, I want to put the variables into groups and remove the duplicate combination based on VarB (for example: D,A is correlated to each other and I want to keep one of the two combination in the final output)

```
VarA <- c('G','D','A','X','E','D','A','X','E','Z','Q')
VarB <- c('H','D','D','E','E','A','A','X','X','Z','Z')
corrout <- as.data.frame(cbind(VarA,VarB))

VarA      VarB
 G          H
 D          D
 A          D
 X          E
 E          E
 D          A
 A          A
 X          X
 E          X
 Z          Z
 Q          Z
```

The desired out below shown is based on VarB and two duplicates are removed in the output A,A and X,X combination of VarB as its already listed above.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT

GROUP1 - G
GROUP2 - D,A
GROUP3 - X,E
GROUP4 - Z,Q
```

Hope somebody will be able to help me with a simple funtion for this!! thanks a lot..

Comment: `library(igraph) ; 
g <- graph_from_data_frame(corrout) ; clusters(g)` almost gets you there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(corrout)[, toString(unique(VarA)) , VarB], by = "V1")[,
         VarB := paste0("Group", 1:.N)][]
#      VarB   V1
# 1: Group1    G
# 2: Group2 D, A
# 3: Group3 X, E
# 4: Group4 Z, Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

Remove rows where both variables are same:

```
> c2 = corrout[corrout$VarA != corrout$VarB,] 
> c2
   VarA VarB
1     G    H
3     A    D
4     X    E
6     D    A
9     E    X
11    Q    Z
```

Sort variables in rows:

```
> c3 = data.frame(t(apply(c2, 1, function(x) sort(x))))
> c3
   X1 X2
1   G  H
3   A  D
4   E  X
6   A  D
9   E  X
11  Q  Z
```

Remove duplicates:

```
> c3[!duplicated(c3), ]
   X1 X2
1   G  H
3   A  D
4   E  X
11  Q  Z
```

Comment: When we have correlation with several variables, this is an issue right ? Say for example A is correlated with D, P, Q, R, S in that case we need to group it and the dataframe result will be an issue I guess..

Comment: Size of corrout data.frame will not matter. You may even have more columns.